# How can I set the value of an id in the template part of a directive?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am trying this:

http://plnkr.co/edit/IzhScWwcy6owjsPKm2Fs?p=preview

```
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app="plunker" >
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>AngularJS Plunker</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <script>document.write("<base href=\"" + document.location + "\" />");</script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.2/angular.js"></script>
  <script src="app.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    xx<div admin-select
      admin-id="examType"></div>xx
</body>
</html>
```

and

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {

});

app.directive("adminSelect", function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        require: 'ngModel',
        scope: {
            adminId: '=adminId'
        },
        template: '<div id="{{adminId}}"></div>'
    };
});
```

This is not working and I cannot see why. Can someone give me some advice and help me to set the id of the `<div>` that's part of the template.

Comment: <div id="{{id}}" double braces ?

Comment: This is just a typo in the question. The plunker example is correct

Comment: do u have a value for `id: '=adminId'` ?

Comment: Make the `=` to `@` [plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/jWJxbzcsA28cHhDzasOj?p=preview).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to put the value of the `admin-id` attribute under apostrophe because you want to set the value. [Example](http://plnkr.co/edit/dJIrowcxmOUt5kwyiGpS?p=preview)

```
<div admin-select admin-id="'examType'"></div>
```

Otherwise you set the scope variable in the controller and pass this variable to the directive:

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.myId = 'examType'
});

<div admin-select admin-id="myId"></div>
```

[Example](http://plnkr.co/edit/B9Fbhd7OXJTWcuQ54aS7?p=preview)

Answer (score 0):

```
template: '<div id="{{$parent.adminId}}"></div>'
```

Angular's docs has this "*the root of the template always gets a new scope.*", maybe that's why.

**Upddated**

this answer is not working... =)